# How to construct field tower?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to prove  or to disprove that the field  of rational functions $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ over the rationals contains two subfields $K$ and $F$ such that $[\mathbb{Q}(x):K] < \infty$  and $[\mathbb{Q}(x):F] < \infty$  but $[\mathbb{Q}(x):K \cap F] = \infty$?

Comment: How do you know this happens?

Comment: @ Mariano Suarez-Alvarez : Thank you. It has been fixed.

Comment: Would [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/134258/11619) help?

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen: Thank you for the interest to the question. It should be a more or less simple answer because the question was asked at one of student mathematical olimpiads in Ukraine.

Comment: Olympiad kids (and others) can fire simple questions that may not have a simple answer. Anyway, may be you can use [the answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/134455/11619) by a sadly gone user? Does not use  Galois theory AFAICT.

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen: Indeed, your cited answer also answers the question under consideration. In fact, your answer uses authomorphisms. AFAIUI, that belongs to Galois theory. However, I accept the one as the answer to my question.

Comment: If it is "students" mathematics Olim. then it probably contains stuff at undergraduate level, of which Galois Theory undoubtedly is part of. If it was a high school mathematics olympics...wow, are you kidding me? This would be the first time in my life I've ever seen such a question at this level for high school kids!

Comment: @ DonAntonio : the question  is not from a school mathematical olimpiad.