# Intersection of two subfields of $F(X)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $E=F(x)$ for a field $F$ of characteristic $0$.
>   Show that $F(x^2) \cap F(x^2-x) = F$ as subfields of $F(x)$.

I could use a hand with this... Thanks

Comment: This has been asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1742059/11619) and answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/134258/11619) though with a minor change in the sign. You can easily accomodate for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s another argument, assuming that $x$ is transcendental over $F$, i.e. just an indeterminate.

We have two automorphisms of $E$, namely $\sigma:x\mapsto-x$ and $\tau:x\mapsto1-x$. Both are involutions, so the fixed fields are both of degree two beneath $E$, and as you see, they are $F(x^2)$ and $F(x^2-x)$ respectively.

Certainly any element of $F(x^2)\cap F(x^2-x)$ will be fixed under both $\sigma$ and $\tau$, thus fixed under their composition. What about $\sigma\circ\tau$? It sends $x$ to $x+1$, so in a field of characteristic zero, it’s not torsion, i.e. not of finite order.Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial (or rational function) fixed by $\sigma\circ\tau$. If $\xi$ is a root of $f$ in any finite extension of $F$, then $\xi+n$ is also a root, so $f$ has infinitely many roots or none. Thus it’s constant.

I think you’ll find that in characteristic $p\ne2$, $(x^p-x)^2$ is fixed under both your automorphisms.

Answer (score 0):

Any non-constant polynomial over F in $x^2$ has *only* terms of even degree in $x$.  Any non-constant polynomial over F in $x^2 - x$ *necessarily* has terms of odd degree in $x$.  In particular, a polynomial $f(y)$ of degree N, evaluated at $x^2 - x$, has a term in $x$ of degree 2N-1 generated by the degree N term in $y$, and no lower-degree term in $y$, evaluated at $x^2 - x$, can generate a term in $x$ of equal degree, so the coefficients of $f(y)$ cannot 'conspire' to cancel out all the odd-degree terms in $x$.  It follows that the intersection must be F.

*[I think this argument even works when the characteristic is non-zero]*

Comment: In characteristic three, $(x^2-x)^3\,+\,(x^2-x)^2 =x^6+x^4+x^2$.