# prove $[E:K\cap L]=[E:K][E:L]$

Tags: galois-theory

Let $E/K,E/L$ be finite Galois extensions with Galois groups $G,H$. If $G\cap H= \left\{1\right\}$, show $G\cdot H = \left\{ g h \mid g\in G,h\in H \right\}$ is a group iff $[E:K\cap L]=[E:K][E:L]$.

But isn't the set $G\cdot H$ always a group? The condition $G\cap H= \left\{1\right\}$ implies $KL=E$ and then there's a theorem saying $[KL:L]=[K:L\cap K]$ which is different...

Comment: What do you mean $\;G\cap H=0\;$ ? Do you mean you know the Galois groups are abelian and then, for some reason, you're writing the operations additively and zero is the unit element? But then you take *the product* $\;GH\;$ ...? Now, for the question to make sense you must be able to embed both groups in a bigger group, otherwise $\;GH\;$ isn't even defined, and once you've done this: **no**, product of subgroups isn't a subgroup in general.

Comment: I fixed the 0 to {1}. Okay, the product isn't a subgroup cause they group aren't abelian. What do I do here?

Comment: Nop, not being abelian is *not* a reason for the product of two subgroups not being a subgroup. If $\;G\;$ is any group and $\;H,K\le G\;$ , then $\;HK\le G\iff HK=KH\;$ . This is a basic exercise in basic group theory. Thus, for example, it is enough to require that one of the subgroups is normal for the product to be a subgroup (but **not** necessary). Anyway: in what bigger group are you going to embed your groups $\;G,H\;$ so that the product $\;GH\;$ is even defined, to begin with?

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm not sure.. sorry..

Comment: Don't be. It is just that your problem cannot be properly attacked, leave alone, solved, without that info. Either you're omitting some relevant data, or this is part of another, bigger question, etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio that's really all I have

Comment: @DonAntonio what are some conditions on the extensions making the equality $[E:K\cap L]=[E:K][E:L]$ true?

Comment: Are you sure about $[KL:L]=[L:L\cap K]$? Because putting that together with $KL=E$ gives you $[E:L]=[L:L\cap K]$, and comparing that to $[E:K\cap L]=[E:K][E:L]$ and $[E:K\cap L]=[E:L][L:K\cap L]$ tells you $[E:L]=[E:K]$, which seems unlikely.

Comment: Gerry mentions a good point. I think the theorem should probably be $\;[KL:L]=[\color{red}K:K\cap L]$

Comment: You are both right of course, sorry. I corrected my question. As far as embedding in a larger group, maybe $\mathrm{Aut}_E(K\cap L)$ works?

Comment: @user355165 That's exactly what I'm trying to do in a comment that was too long and thus is becoming now an answer...

Comment: I shall need more time for this as there are some things that look suspicious and/or I don't remember well.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think a few applications of theorem 2.6 [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoiscorrthms.pdf) are needed.

Comment: @Arrow Perhaps so, yet the OP's question is not about two different *extensions* of one single basis field, but rather about two different *subextensions* of the same field with **different** basis fields. This is what confuses me here, though I was thinking perhaps getting into quotient groups we could use somehow that th. 2.6 you say. Thank you.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think along with $[LK:L]=[K:L\cap K]$ and its mirror version the formula $[LK:L\cap K]=\frac{[L:L\cap K][K:L\cap K]}{[L\cap K:L\cap K]}=[L:L\cap K][K:L\cap K]$ resolves everything, so the problem reduces to justifying its use.

Comment: @DonAntonio do you have any insight to share on this problem?

Comment: $[KL:L\cap K]=[L:L\cap K]\cdot [K:L\cap K]$ if and only if $L$ and $K$ are *linearly disjoint* over $L\cap K$. This is automatic, when both $L$ and $K$ are Galois over $L\cap K$.

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong with the title of this question. Namely the claim in the title is false without some extra assumptions.

Consider the following example.

Let $E=\Bbb{C}(x)$ be the field of rational functions. Let $G$ be the cyclic group of order two generated by the $\Bbb{C}$-automorphism $\sigma:x\mapsto -x$. We immediately see that the fixed field of $G$ is the subfield $K=\Bbb{C}(x^2)$.

Let $H$ be the cyclic group of order two generated by the $\Bbb{C}$-automorphism $\tau:x\mapsto 1-x$. We easily see that the corresponding fixed field is $L=\Bbb{C}(x^2-x)$.

But in this case it is easy to show that
$$
K\cap L=\Bbb{C}.
$$
See [this thread and my old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/134258/11619) for a proof of that fact. Anyway, here
$$
[E:L]=[E:K]=2,\quad [E:K\cap L]=\infty.
$$

Note that in this case $\sigma\tau:x\mapsto x+1$, so $\sigma\tau$ is of infinite order. Therefore $GH$, a set with only four elements, most certainly is not a group.

---

Answering one direction. Assume that $G\cdot H$ is a group, call it $\Omega$. Because $G\cap H=\{1\}$ we know that $|\Omega|=|G|\cdot |H|$, in particular we know that $\Omega$ is finite. By Artin's lemma the fixed field $F=E^\Omega$ has the properties that
$[E:F]=|\Omega|$ and $Gal(E/F)=\Omega$. Because $\Omega$ is the smallest group containing both $G$ and $H$, Galois correspondence tells us that $F$ is the largest subfiel contained in both $K$ and $L$. Therefore $F=K\cap L$. Also,
$$
[E:K\cap L]=[E:F]=|\Omega|=|G|\cdot |H|=[E:K]\cdot [E:L].
$$

---

[Edit:]

I think the other direction follows from the following line of thought. Assume that $[E:K\cap L]=|G|\cdot |H|$. Clearly $K\cap L$ is fixed pointwise by all the automorphisms of $E$ that are of the form $gh$. Because $G$ and $H$ intersect trivially, all the automorphisms of this form are distinct. Therefore
$|Aut(E/K\cap L)|\ge |G|\cdot |H|$. On the other hand for a finite extension $E/F$ we have $|Aut(E/F)|\le [E:F]$ and here there is equality if and only if $E/F$ is Galois. Therefore we can conclude that $E/(K\cap L)$ is Galois, and
$Aut(E/K\cap L)=G\cdot H$. In particular, $G\cdot H$ is a group.