# Hungerford exercise V.2.8

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, cyclic-groups

**Assume $\operatorname{char}K = 0$ and let $G$ be the subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}_K K(x)$ that is generated by the automorphism induced by $x\mapsto x + 1_K.$ Then $G$ is an infinite cyclic group. Determine the fixed field $E$ of $G.$ What is $[K(x) : E]$?**

I think that this exercise begin by using first part of Artin's lemma and get $K(x)$ is Galois over $E.$ I.e., $G < \operatorname{Aut}(K(x)/E)$, we get $E=G'=G'''=E''$ lemma V.2.6-(iv) of Hungerford.

But I don't know how to proceed. Can someone help me?

Comment: 1. Please use MathJax; [here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). 2. Please do not use images: they are not searchable, making it harder for your post to be found later; they are not accessible (as you did not provide descriptive text of the image when you added it) so that users who employ screen readers cannot tell what is in the image; and they are not adjustable, so they may be badly sized depending on the display being used. This is very short text; please replace the image with its content in properly formatted text

Comment: An argument is buried in [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/134336/11619). That question is nominally about the fixed field of a dihedral group containing your group as an index two subgroup. However, I think you can use that argument.