# The intersection $F(X^2)\cap F(X^2-X)$ for fields of characteristic zero

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I am trying to understand the solution to the following exercise from Milne's notes on Galois theory (available [here](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ft.html)):

---

[image]

---

At the end of the notes, the author presents the following solution to the problem:

---

[image]

---

Although I understand the argument, it is not immediately clear to me that this contradiction implies $F(X^2)\cap F(X^2-X)=F$. What immediately follows is that there are no *polynomials* of degree $m>0$ in this intersection. However, $E=F(X^2)\cap F(X^2-X)$ is a field of rational functions, so, in principle, it is not clear why there couldn't be non-constant rational functions $p(X)/q(X)$ in this field, even if there are no polynomials. More precisely, I can formulate my question as follows:

- **How to show that, if there exists $p(X)/q(X)\in E$, with $p, q$ coprime, $q(X)\neq0$, and $\deg(q)>0$, then there exists a polynomial of degree $m>0$ in $E$?**

This way, we would demonstrate that $E$ indeed contains no non-constant rational functions and, therefore, $E=F$.

Comment: This reminds me of [an older thread I happened to answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/134258/11619). Do the explanations there help you?

Comment: If the intersection $E$ is bigger than $F$ then the intersection must be of the form $F(f(X)) $ (Luroth theorem) for some rational function $f(X) $ and then $[F(f(X)) :F(X)] $ is finite and has at most a finite number of automorphisms.

Comment: Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen! It was very helpful!

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The author of the notes has not yet presented Lüroth's Theorem in the chapter I am currently reading, but I will revisit the question later after becoming familiar with this result. Thanks!